# Desabilitando TextBox não preenchidos

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um software em c# para contabilizar o numero de tornozeleiras eletrônicas que vão dentro de uma caixa. Esta caixa tem espaço para armazenar 40 tornozeleiras. No caso do Software coloquei 40 txtbox onde cada um representa o numero de série de cada tornozeleira. Como ocorre do operador as vezes repetir a mesma tornozeleira em txtbox diferentes, com a ajuda de um conhecido desenvolvi este método a baixo que indica se há valores repetidos dentro dessas txtbox que no caso foram colocadas em uma Array[39]. Até ai tudo bem, o que ocorre é que nem sempre os 40 txtbox são preenchidos porque as vezes as caixas vão incompletas, o problema é que o método indica erro de duplicidade porque como há campos que ficam vazios, talvez ele entenda como se estivessem repetindo valores. Gostaria de saber se, tem como eu desabilitar os textbox que não forem preenchidos. Essa condição do código abaixo foi posta no btsalvararquivo. Botei o codigo onde eu capturo as informações das textbox na Array e ele faz uma verificação.

Código:

```
    private void BtnSair_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }

    //Evento onde é feita a verificação de duplicidade da etiqueta.
    private void BtnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int64[] valores = new Int64[40];
        //RATE 01-10
        valores[0] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text);
        valores[1] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox3.Text);
        valores[2] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox4.Text);
        valores[3] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox5.Text);
        valores[4] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox6.Text);
        valores[5] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox7.Text);
        valores[6] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox8.Text);
        valores[7] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox9.Text);
        valores[8] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox10.Text);
        valores[9] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox11.Text);

        //RATE 11-20
        valores[10] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox12.Text);
        valores[11] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox13.Text);
        valores[12] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox14.Text);
        valores[13] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox15.Text);
        valores[14] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox16.Text);
        valores[15] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox17.Text);
        valores[16] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox18.Text);
        valores[17] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox19.Text);
        valores[18] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox20.Text);
        valores[19] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox21.Text);

        //RATE 21-30
        valores[20] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox22.Text);
        valores[21] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox23.Text);
        valores[22] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox24.Text);
        valores[23] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox25.Text);
        valores[24] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox26.Text);
        valores[25] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox27.Text);
        valores[26] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox28.Text);
        valores[27] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox29.Text);
        valores[28] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox30.Text);
        valores[29] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox31.Text);

        //RATE 31-40
        valores[30] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox32.Text);
        valores[31] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox33.Text);
        valores[32] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox34.Text);
        valores[33] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox35.Text);
        valores[34] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox36.Text);
        valores[35] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox37.Text);
        valores[36] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox38.Text);
        valores[37] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox39.Text);
        valores[38] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox40.Text);
        valores[39] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox41.Text);

        //Verificando a Duplicidade 
        int quant_campos = valores.Length;
        var groups = valores.Distinct().ToList();


        if (quant_campos > groups.Count)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EXISTEM VALORES DUPLICADOS", "ATENÇÃO!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

        }

        return;
```

Comment: Luiz, sua pergunta não esta clara o suficiente para que possar se entendida e redigida uma resposta, favor edita-la de uma forma que fique melhor o entendimento. Por exemplos como você esta fazendo para ler os txtbox ? e como eles são carregados? onde o erro esta ocorrendo ?

Comment: int quant_groups = valores.Where(item => item != null).length;  ou var quant_groups = valores.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)).length;

Comment: Ficar dificil da uma resposta sem sabe o que você esta manipulando, acredito que a sua verificação possar ser mais simples do que esta tentando fazer.

Comment: botei mais informações de código, por favor verifique se ficou mais claro onde estou querendo chegar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código tem varias falhas graves que podem causa erro na hora de da execução,

1. Se o usuário digita um caracteres que não seja número você vai ter um erro de conversão. `Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text);`
2. Muito estranho você especificar que possar ocorrer duplicidade devido algum campo não ser preenchido, se ele ficar como NULL você também terá o erro acima.
3. Você poderia especificar para o usuário qual o campo esta em duplicidade.

Eu montei o código abaixo com um começo de como você pode valida seu código, basta segui a logica e dar continuidade com o restante dos campos, mas mesmo assim repensaria melhor em uma forma de fazer isso.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //Evento onde é feita a verificação de duplicidade da etiqueta.
        private void BtnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int64[] valores = new Int64[40];
            //RATE 01-10
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && checarString(textBox1.Text))
                valores[0] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) && checarString(textBox3.Text))
            {   
                // usar o linq para verificar se existem textBox iguais
                if (!valores.Any(v => v.Equals(Convert.ToInt64(textBox3.Text))))
                {
                    valores[1] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox3.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    messageBoxButtons();
                }
            }

            valores[2] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox4.Text);
            valores[3] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox5.Text);
            valores[4] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox6.Text);
            valores[5] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox7.Text);
            valores[6] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox8.Text);
            valores[7] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox9.Text);
            valores[8] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox10.Text);
            valores[9] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox11.Text);

            //RATE 11-20
            valores[10] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox12.Text);
            valores[11] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox13.Text);
            valores[12] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox14.Text);
            valores[13] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox15.Text);
            valores[14] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox16.Text);
            valores[15] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox17.Text);
            valores[16] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox18.Text);
            valores[17] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox19.Text);
            valores[18] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox20.Text);
            valores[19] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox21.Text);

            //RATE 21-30
            valores[20] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox22.Text);
            valores[21] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox23.Text);
            valores[22] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox24.Text);
            valores[23] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox25.Text);
            valores[24] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox26.Text);
            valores[25] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox27.Text);
            valores[26] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox28.Text);
            valores[27] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox29.Text);
            valores[28] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox30.Text);
            valores[29] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox31.Text);

            //RATE 31-40
            valores[30] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox32.Text);
            valores[31] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox33.Text);
            valores[32] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox34.Text);
            valores[33] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox35.Text);
            valores[34] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox36.Text);
            valores[35] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox37.Text);
            valores[36] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox38.Text);
            valores[37] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox39.Text);
            valores[38] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox40.Text);
            valores[39] = Convert.ToInt64(textBox41.Text);

            return;
        }
        // verifica se realmente é só números
        public bool checarString(string str)
        {
            char[] c = str.ToCharArray();
            char le = ' ';
            for (int cont = 0; cont < c.Length; cont++)
            {
                le = c[cont];
                if (!char.IsDigit(le))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        // retorna a mensagem ... pense em passar como parâmetros os campos duplicados ....
        public void messageBoxButtons()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EXISTEM VALORES DUPLICADOS", "ATENÇÃO!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Realmente o método que você informou funcionou, só que não pegou foi a parte de verificar se o campo estava sendo preenchido com com Letras, mas resolvi isso usando o fazendo um método e puxando direto do keypress da Textbox. Só oque falta é desenvolver o método pra que ele mostre ao usuário quais os TextBox estão repetindo, ou pelo menos marcar com Cor, que é oque fiz. Não deu muito certo mas adicionei um "TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Yellow . Não deu muito certo pois ele so marca a segunda box repetida.

Comment: Para você ter uma ideia de qual é o primeiro você teria que localiza o index do arrey com o valor duplicado, ai você iria saber qual foi o textbox que inseriu o valor nele.